# React component rerendering weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a react app where you have a "login" screen (just add a username to go in).
I have used [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to do what I want(basically after submitting a username, it should change the component rendering)
My problem is that each time I click the submit button and the main component re-renders it will change the state of the main component back to default. The result is that it will show the Game component, which is a generic one, for a split second then go back to rendering the login component. What am I doing wrong?

Main component:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      loggedIn : false
    };
  }

  login() {
    this.setState({loggedIn: true});
  }
  
  render() {

    const isLoggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;
    
    return (
      <div>
        {isLoggedIn 
        ? <Game/>
        : <Login login={this.login}/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The login component:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    console.log("HELLO")
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // login/" + this.state.value
    fetch("my.api.example")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.onLogin();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }

  onLogin = () => {
    
    this.props.login();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your handleSubmit doesn't have a `event.preventDefault()` so I'm guessing the form is submitting and refreshing the page.

Comment: Agree with James. Another way (which prevents the whole issue) is to use `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick={this.handleSubmit} />` and then perhaps even kick out the `<form>` element, which does not have much reason to exist because you don't want to post data to a server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your handleSubmit doesn't have an `event.preventDefault()` so the form is submitting and refreshing the page.